# Can we enter html code in a field in models in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a small static website in which I have a template in which I tend to show the privacy policy terms of usage etc. I currently don't have any matter for it and tend to add it in future after deploying the site on server. I wanted to know that if I can in future add the matter on that page through a model i.e I create a model with two fields privacy policy , terms and in and pass it to the template as context in views.py . But I have a concern that the fields will have several headings which I will have to display in bold , so is there any way that I can pass html tags in model field and when I render it in my template as {{privacy}} the part I want in bold or any other style comes as that style.

Comment: you can change in the html itself as you dont need to manipulate with the data. So, you can add it directly there.

Comment: I am creating it for someone else and its more of a project kind of thing so I wouldnt be able to open the code after deploying it on the server so I wish to add it by going to admin panel and it in the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is there any way that I can pass html tags in model field and when I render it in my template as `{{privacy}}` the part I want in bold or any other style comes as that style.

**Yes**. You only need to tell the Django template engine *not* to escape the characters (for example translate `<` to `&lt;`). You can do this with the [**`|safe`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
{{ privacy|safe }}
```

Comment: @rohitbumrah: it will simply render the HTML content without escaping it. So the browser will read `<br>` and produce a new line.